# Render view works but final rendering fails with RTX 2070

Tags: rendering

So, I upgraded my Gpu from an rx 470 to an rtx 2070, everything works with the rtx 2070 except the final rendering (render view still works)[image]. I tried to reinstall Blender and all the drivers (Nvidia and Amd Chipset) and changing settings in Blender (Prefrences and Render engine) after all of that no crashing just the default empty grid.

I have reset all options and restarted the computer several times!

Specs:
Rtx 2070 (CUDA in Blender enabled)
ryzen 3600
16gb ram

Blender versions tried 2.82-2.83.1
Windows 10
Games like Rainbow 6 run fine

Thanks for helping

Comment: Does Blender throw an error message when you render? If so, what is it?

Comment: Is the rendered image empty?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of render window, where empty grid appears?

Comment: no error, indefinitely rendering/loading. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wG9ka2u-I5hHOhkJI7cPDw4UNQGdUyo8/view?usp=sharing